# Python function returning objects insted of values

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, data-structures

I have a python class, and this class has functions as follows
:

```
import numpy as np

class output_hidden:

    def feature(self,x1,y1):
        feature=np.array([x1,y1])
        return feature
    def weights(self):
        self.weights = np.random.rand(2,1)
        return weights

object_1=output_hidden()
value_of_feature = object_1.feature(0.05, 0.10)
```

I have supplied values to the class `feature` and this is its output:

```
>>> print(value_of_feature)
[0.05 0.1 ]
```

However when I want to return values stored in weights I get

```
>>> print(object_1.weights)
<bound method output_hidden.weights of <__main__.output_hidden object at 0x7ff88b7fb860>>
```

What I want for `print(object_1.weights` is  = `[[0.29707055]
 [0.04773819]]`

What am I missing why aren't I getting my expected results ?

Comment: You need to call the method: `object_1.weights()` and don't do `self.weights` you already have a method called `weights`

Answer (score 0):

you need to use return self.weights (since weights isn't defined)

```
import numpy as np

class output_hidden:

    def feature(self,x1,y1):
        feature=np.array([x1,y1])
        return feature
    def weights(self):
        self.weights = np.random.rand(2,1)
        return self.weights

object_1=output_hidden()
value_of_feature = object_1.feature(0.05, 0.10)

print(object_1.weights)

[[0.362058  ]
 [0.89373472]]
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the values you need to do it like this: `print(object_1.weights())`.
You need to invoke the method.

or else what you are doing is printing the method and what Python gives you is the method type (bound), instance type to which it belongs and the address of the instance.